# Loading html page in the background

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, background, loading

I want to display to the user an initial page with some loading animation while loading the main page in the background.

Once the main page is loaded, the first page will redirect the browser to the main page.

I've tried putting the animation and the main page content on one page, but it still taking a long time until the user sees the animation itself.

Simple loading example I've tried in [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pb96okjL/2/). The real page contains much more content.

```
<div id="preloader">
  <div id="loader"></div>
</div>
<div id="map"></div>
```

Comment: try to load resource required for loading animation as soon as possible, it's taking long time because you might be loading heavy resources such as JS libraries even before animation itself.

Comment: I'm loading a lot of JS in the head section. That is why I'm thinking of using two pages.